# Array of objects dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, class, memory-management

I'm trying to allocate dynamic memory to an array of objects, but I keep getting the following error:

"error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'"
"error: C2501: 'Figura' : missing storage-class or type specifiers"

Any help is welcomed. I'm using Visual Basic C++ 2006, but will switch to Turbo C++ 3.0 with Dosbox to get graphics.h working :( .

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream.h>

class Grup {
    private:
        int nr_elemente;
        Figura *figuri;
    public:
        Grup() {
            figuri = new Figura[nr_elemente];
        }
};


class Figura {

public:
    Figura();
    ~Figura();
    Figura(const Figura&);

    friend Figura operator+(const Figura& fig1, const Figura& fig2) {};
    friend Figura operator+(const Grup& gr1, const Grup& gr2) {}

    friend Figura operator*(const Figura& fig) {}
    friend Figura operator*(const Figura& fig) {}

};

Figura operator+(const Figura& fig, const Grup& gr) {
    return fig;
}

class Punct : Figura
{
public:
    int x, y;

    Punct(int x, int y) {
        Punct::x = x;
        Punct::y = y;
    }
};

class Segment : Figura
{
public:
    int x, y, poz;
};

class Dreptunghi : Figura
{
public:
    int x, y, poz;
};

void main(void) {



}
```

Comment: Turbo C++ 3.0 is from 1991. Not recommended for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
figuri = new Figura[nr_elemente];
```

The compiler does not know that a class `Figura` exists. Therefore, it generates an error, since "Figura" is an unknown token at that point. You should use a forward declaration:

```
class Figura; // forward-declare class Figura

class Grup {
/* ... */
};


class Figura {
/* ... */
};
```

The problem is that the compiler does not know the size of a class `Figura`, therefore it can't allocate an array of objects of this type. Therefore you will probably need to use pointers or modify your class design.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of how can I use pointers instead of what I am doing now?

Comment: Doesn't he need the complete Figura class for the call to new to work?

Comment: Ok, i forward-declared Figura, but now getting "no appropriate default constructor available." at the line with figuri = new Figura[nr_elemente];

Comment: @Bdesign you need to declare ***and*** define `Figura` before `Grup` as I said in my answer..

Comment: Hmmm I think I should consider redesigning the classes a little.

Comment: @juanchopanza yes, that's what I said in my last paragraph. He can't declare and define `Figura` and `Grup` since both of them require the other's definition. OP probably requiress some modification in his design.

Comment: it is OK with a fwd declaration of `Figura`, but yes, the whole thing looks like it needs to be redesigned.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to do all in one file. You'll not have such kind of problems if you move the declaration and definition of classes to separate `.hpp` and `.cpp` files. 
Move

```
// file grup.hpp

class Figura; // forward declaration

class Grup {
private:
    int nr_elemente;
    Figura *figuri;
public:
    Grup();
};
```

to `grup.hpp` file. Then implement the constructor of `Grup` in `group.cpp` file:

```
// file grup.cpp
#include "grup.hpp"
#include "figura.hpp"


Grup::Grup()
{
    figuri = new Figura[nr_elemente];
}
```

Also move the definition and declaration of Figura class to corresponding `figura.hpp` and `figura.cpp` files. Better to use the same approach with all classes you have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to forward declare, already mentioned, but that is not enough, you need to know the size of the class in order to use it as an implementation.  Therefore...

```
class Figura;
class Grup{
  Figura * figuri;
  //.. other stuff, but ONLY declarations no implementations.
};

class Figura
{
  //Same as you already have...
};
```

After the classes have been declared, since they are in the same file you need to implement AFTER the other classes have been implemented (or declared).

```
//Still same file but below the Figura class definition..
Grup::Grup() {
   //Now you can use Figura...
   figuri = new Figura[nr_elemente];
}
```

@be
The problem you are seeing with your comment below has to do with the assignment operator for your fig class.

The operator looks like this...
     Fig& operator=(const Fig& );

But with your example you are assigning a pointer
     void func(const Fig * fig)
     {
      //...
      figcontainer[index] = fig; // if you did *fig; you would be ok
      //...
     }

Comment: I did a little redesigning and now almost everything works. The only problem is I think I'm not doing the dynamic memory allocation right. I get : error C2679: binary '=' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type 'class Figura *' . The line is : void adauga_element(Figura *fig) {
   figuri[nr_elemente++] = fig;
  } .